# How to chain the css3 transition in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css

Here is my scenario,

when user click on button, I need to increase the height of `div` once that `div` reached the height,

from the child of `div` each of `span` need to have `opacity:1`, by sequence (with some delay between spans)

How to do this?

here is my code and demo:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
myApp.controller('main', function($scope){
    $scope.animate = false;
    $scope.animIt = function () {
        $scope.animate = !$scope.animate;
    }
})

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="main">
    <div  ng-class="{'active' : animate}">
        <span>Testing1</span>
        <span>Testing2</span>
        <span>Testing3</span>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="animIt()">Click Me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9jEp/159/)

**UPDATE**
Step of what i required:

1. make full height to div
2. `div` reach the full height and start
3. first `span` fade in and that's done
4. next `span` fade in like so..
5. when user clicks again remove `active` from div
6. when `div` reducing height, accodingly fade out the `span` by reverse order.

Comment: You should able to do this task easily with the library by Greensock.com
http://greensock.com/tweenmax . I suggest you check it out. It is very easy to use it in angularjs as well.

Comment: no, i am looking for css3 and `angular` approach. library may not allowed by some customers.

Comment: Here is my try mixing with `jQuery`, still any one help me to get the result? http://jsfiddle.net/s9jEp/157/